# Add UIView banner above status bar iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios7-statusbar

I'm trying to add a banner above the status bar when receiving an in-app push notification. From what I've been reading, it seems like the only way to dynamically change the status bar style in iOS 7 is to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO`. This is not only really annoying to have to change all my different view controllers `prefersStatusBarHidden` to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden`, but it also doesn't give the effect I'm looking for.

When the banner slides from the top, I still want the 20 pts of space that the status bar provides to stay, but the status bar content to disappear until after the banner slides back up. Is there a way to either do this or add a subview or window above the status bar?

Basically I'm looking to do this:

[image: Facebook Messenger push banner]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Create a new window and add your banner view to that window. When you need to show the banner, you can set `yourwindow.hidden = NO;` You can further add animations to showing it and to dismiss it `yourwindow.hidden = YES;`.

The key here is is setting `yourwindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1;`

That will make sure your banner view and the `yourwindow` always appear above the status bar.

Feel free to ask questions regarding any of the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The line `yourwindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1;` was the key. As a follow up, the status bar style is white before the banner shows, but changes to black once it shows and disappears. How can I force the status bar to turn white again without having to leave the screen and come back?

Comment: Nevermind. I was doing `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` instead of just `window.hidden = NO;` Works perfectly!

Comment: Hey @dezinezync , how to add my custom `UIWindow` to my view when I want to show that custom status view?

Comment: @dee you don't add it to any particular view. You simply use myWindow.hidden = NO. If you'd like, you can position the frame of the window in a way that it appears as a part of your view. I could be wrong, and there could be a better way given that UIWindow is a specialized UIView, but at the time of writing this, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: @dezinezync , thanks for your answer. I'm getting confused, there's no need to add the window to it's superview to show it? I follower your tip , and I can show the window without attaching it to a superview , but when I update the window's subview , the subview won't be changed.Why?

Comment: uiwindow over status works fine but only in portrait mode. how to handle the rotation? please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976494/ios-8-7-uiwindow-with-uiwindowlevelstatusbar-rotation-issue

Answer (score 46):

To put your view controller above status bar:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1];
```

To put your view controller behind status bar:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks Nico!! To make screenshots for launch images it's very helpful to make status bar transparent or hide it behind the window! You saved my day

Answer (score 4):

Add UIView banner above status bar-Swift4

```
func showBannerView(bannerView:UIView){
     let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    window.addSubview(bannerView)
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1
}
func removeBannerView(bannerView:UIView){
    bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar - 1

}
```

Comment: What to do with iPhone X

Comment: You need to add 30px top padding to the banner view content while using this on iphone x.