# UIView above UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uiview, z-index, uialertview

In my app, a lock screen is used. Sometimes a `UIAlertView` is shown, now when the user sends the app to the background and brings it in front again, the `UIAlertview` is shown above the lock screen. Is there a possibility to add a `UIViewController`'s view above everything, i.e. above the `UIAlertView`?

Comment: Smiler sort of problem to what you need to do, so I hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241412/add-uiview-banner-above-status-bar-ios-7

Comment: One way to sidestep the problem might be to maintain a reference of your `UIAlertView`, and hide it when the app enters the background. When the app enters the foreground again, it's up to you to decide what you do with the alertView reference.

Comment: Good question. But I think `UIAlertView` is supposed to be on top of everything - that's its duty - to alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have like this

```
UIWindow *mySpecialWindowForLockScreen = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

//"Hey iOS Please put this window above all alert view"
mySpecialWindowForLockScreen.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert+100;

UIViewController *lockScreenViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];//Lock Screen

lockScreenViewController.view.frame = mySpecialWindowForLockScreen.bounds;

mySpecialWindowForLockScreen.rootViewController = lockScreenViewController;


// In lockScreenViewController view you can add lock screen images and other UI stuff
mySpecialWindowForLockScreen.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[mySpecialWindowForLockScreen makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Whenever you want to hide the LockScreen window then simply hide it by setHidden:YES.

Comment: now it works for me as well; the problem was that ARC cleaned up the ```mySpecialWindowForLockScreen``` immediately, therefore I had to make a property for it.

Answer (score 2):

There are three kind of UIWindowLevel, the biggest one will be shown above the other window.

So I suggest you use a UIWindow to create your lock screen and let it's window level bigger than `UIWindowLevelAlert`,

Basically, their values are :

```
 UIWindowLevelNormal = 0.000000;
 UIWindowLevel UIWindowLevelAlert = 2000.000000;
 UIWindowLevel UIWindowLevelStatusBar = 1000.000000;
```

so that's why the alert view will show above the other window.have a try.